# How to pass value from Vue prompt to JS variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, variables

I am using the [Buefy UI Components](https://buefy.org/documentation/dialog) and would like to pass on the `$(value)` outside the function to use it in an `alert(thevalue)` or something like that. Tried to find a solution out there, but haven't found a helpful one. So I am very thankful for your support on this!

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button
                class="button is-medium is-dark"
                @click="prompt">
                Launch prompt (default)
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        prompt() {
            this.$buefy.dialog.prompt({
                message: `What's your name?`,
                inputAttrs: {
                    placeholder: 'e.g. Walter',
                    maxlength: 10
                },
                trapFocus: true,
                onConfirm: (value) => this.$buefy.toast.open(`Your name is: ${value}`)
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value inside the data and call it later by other methods.

Haven't tested this yet, but it should work:

```html
<template>
    <section>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button
                class="button is-medium is-dark"
                @click="prompt">
                Launch prompt (default)
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: ""
        }
    },

    methods: {
        prompt() {
            this.$buefy.dialog.prompt({
                message: `What's your name?`,
                inputAttrs: {
                    placeholder: 'e.g. Walter',
                    maxlength: 10
                },
                trapFocus: true,
                onConfirm: (value) => {
                    // Set name
                    this.name = value;
                    this.$buefy.toast.open(`Your name is: ${value}`);
                }
            })
        },

        other() {
            alert(this.name);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I couldn't get this run.